# Escaping a variable with special characters within sed - comment and uncomment an arbitrary line of source code

Tags: perl, awk, sed, escaping, comments

I need to comment out a line in a crontab file through a script, so it contains directories, spaces and symbols. This specific line is stored in a variable and I am starting to get mixed up on how to escape the variable. Since the line changes on a regular basis I dont want any escaping in there. I don't want to simply add # in front of it, since I also need to switch it around and replace the line again with the original without the #.

So the goal is to replace $line with #$line (comment) with the possibility to do it the other way around (uncomment).

So I have a variable:

```
line="* * * hello/this/line & /still/this/line"
```

This is a line that occurs in a file, file.txt. Wich needs to get comment out.

First try:

```
sed -i "s/^${line}/#${line}/" file.txt
```

Second try:

```
sed -i 's|'${line}'|'"#${line}"'|g' file.txt
```

Comment: As for your own tries: The 1st try fails, because the value of `$line` contains characters that need escaping for use with `s` (the crux of the matter; in this _particular_ case, using `|` as the delimiter would have worked, but that's not a general solution).
The 2nd try makes matters worse, because the _unquoted_ use of `$line` now causes the shell to perform word-splitting and globbing on the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[choroba's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41759172/45375) shows an effective solution using `perl`.

---

#### `sed` solution

If you want to use `sed`, you must **use a separate `sed` command just to escape the `$line` variable value**, because **`sed` has *no* built-in way to escape strings for use as literals in a regex context**:

```
lineEscaped=$(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$line") # escape $line for use in regex
sed -i "s/^$lineEscaped\$/#&/" file.txt # Note the \$ to escape the end-of-line anchor $
```

<sup>With BSD/macOS `sed`, use `-i ''` instead of just `-i` for in-place updating without backup.</sup>

And the reverse (*un*-commenting):

```
sed -i "s/^#\($lineEscaped\)\$/\1/" file.txt
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29613573/45375) of mine for an explanation of the `sed` command used for escaping, which should work with any input string.

Also note how variable `$lineEscaped` is only referenced *once*, in the *regex* portion of the `s` command, whereas the *substitution-string* portion simply references what the regex matched (which avoids the need to escape the variable again, using different rules):
`&` in the substitution string represents the entire match, and `\1` the first capture group (parenthesized subexpression, `\(...\)`).

For simplicity, the second `sed` command uses double quotes in order to embed the value of shell variable `$lineEscaped` in the `sed` script, but it is generally preferable to use *single*-quoted scripts so as to avoid confusion between what the shell interprets up front vs. what `sed` ends up seeing.

For instance, `$` is special to both the shell and `sed`, and in the above script the end-of-line anchor `$` in the `sed` regex must therefore be escaped as `\$` to prevent the shell from interpreting it.
One way to avoid confusion is to selectively splice double-quoted shell-variable references into the otherwise single-quoted script:

```
sed -i 's/^'"$lineEscaped"'$/#&/' file.txt
```

---

#### `awk` solution

**`awk` offers literal string matching**, which obviates the need for escaping:

```
awk -v line="$line" '$0 == line { $0 = "#" $0 } 1' file.txt > $$.tmp && mv $$.tmp file.txt
```

<sup>If you have *GNU* Awk v4.1+, you can use `-i inplace` for in-place updating.</sup>

And the reverse (*un*-commenting):

```
awk -v line="#$line" '$0 == line { $0 = substr($0, 2) } 1' file.txt > $$.tmp && 
  mv $$.tmp file.txt
```

Comment: Thnx for the extensive answer.

Comment: @Swifting My pleasure; glad it helped; I amended the question's title and tags a little to make the question easier to discover by future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Perl has ways to do the quoting/escaping for you:

```
line=$line perl -i~ -pe '$regex = quotemeta $ENV{line}; s/^$regex/#$ENV{line}/' -- input.txt
```

Comment: This adds a # for every line in file.txt

Comment: Thnx, that worked, but how would we adjust this syntax do to it the other way around?

Comment: @Swifting: What do you mean by "other way around"?

Comment: Changing #$ENV{line} in $ENV{line} again.

Comment: The line variable needed an export first in order for your line to work. But I was wondering how to change the syntax to revert the line back to the original, without the # in front of it.

Comment: Might be something like 's/#ENV{line}/ENV{line}/g'?